# Реализация конструктора для класса String C++

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста, я встал в тупик. 
Мне нужно создать пользовательский класс String, унаследованный от родительского в котором реализована функция `at()` и перегружен оператор `operator[ ]`.

В классе String я перегружаю несколько операторов для моих строк: +,>,<,==,!=

Моя цель реализовать  конструктор по умолчанию, который помог бы мне записать символьный массив и затем вывести его. Моя проблема именно и есть в этом, помогите подтолкнуть на идею , как это сделать...

Родительский класс:

```
class TCharArray
{
protected:
    static const size_t LIMIT = 100;
    char str[LIMIT];
public:
    TCharArray();
    ~TCharArray();

    char & at(size_t n)
    {
        if (n >= LIMIT) throw std::out_of_range("Invalid index");
        return str[n];
    }

    char& operator[ ](size_t n)
    {
        if (n < 0 || n >= LIMIT)
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid index" << std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }
        return str[n];
    }

};
```

Класс String:

```
#include "TCharArray.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned un ;

class String : public TCharArray
{
public:
    /*String()
    {
       strcpy_s(str, "");
    }*/
    String() //Именно в этом конструкторе мне нужно сделать реализацию
    {
        char s[LIMIT];

        try { //вылавливаю исключения, если нет то..
            std::cout << "Enter smth: " << std::endl;//прошу ввести строку
            std::cin >> s[LIMIT];//ввожу 
            for (un i = 0; i < LIMIT; i++) {
                at(i);
            }
        }
        catch (std::out_of_range const& exc) {
            std::cout << exc.what() << '\n';
        }
        for (un j = 0; j < LIMIT; j++) {//вывожу 
            std::cout << at(j)<<std::endl;
        }

    }
    String::~String()
    {
        std::cout << "Exit" << std::endl;
    }
    bool operator==(String ss)const
    {
        return (strcmp(str, ss.str) == 0) ? true : false;
    }
    String operator+(String ss) const
    {
        String temp;
        if (strlen(str) + strlen(ss.str) < LIMIT)
        {
            strcpy_s(temp.str, str);
            strcat_s(temp.str, ss.str);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "over!" << std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }
        return temp;
    }
    friend bool operator!= (const String &a,const String &b )
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }
     friend bool operator>(const String& a, const String& b)
    {
        return (strlen(a.str) > strlen(b.str)) ? true : false;
    }
    friend bool operator<(const String& a, const String& b)
     {
         return (strlen(a.str) < strlen(b.str)) ? true : false;
     }
};
```

Comment: Оффтоп: не забывайте классы с такими общими названиями прятать в какой-нибудь свой namespace.

Comment: @vp_arth Понял вас, пока в разработке , поэтому не прячу

Comment: Что конкретно у вас не работает в текущей реализации? Видимо должно быть так at(i) = s[i];

Comment: @Unick `at(i)=s[i];` меняю в следующем `for` s[ j ]. Введенное слово записывается, как нужно, но сейчас ошибка в том что, после моего записанного слова, выводит на консоль непонятные символа, я подозреваю ,что их около 100. Т.е. мой `LIMIT` не правильно привлечен. Я стремлюсь к тому , что я буду записывать 7 записей, и 7 раз просить ввести запись и вывести. Мне кажется ,что 2й `for` должен быть до 8, а мой `LIMIT` и `try` следят за переполнение, правильно понимаю?

Comment: @nikita-gusev Да у вас выводить мусор, видимо ваши циклы должны быть не до LIMIT, а до strlen(s).

Comment: @Unick `for (un i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {at(i) = s[i];}` и вывод `for (un j = 0;j < strlen(s); j++) {std::cout << s[j] << std::endl;}` Все равно мусор..

Comment: Исправил! Ввожу abc , то вывод каждую букву на новой строке, подскажите как их склеить, нужно вызвать оператор + ,Как правильно?

Comment: Уберите std::endl . А ещё попробуйте почитать какую нибудь более мнее хоршоую книгу по C++.

Comment: @Unick уже читаю, спасибо!